# Are Cov(A-B) and Mean(A-B) equal to Cov(A)-Cov(B) and Mean(A)-Mean(B)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, covariance

If $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are real value matrices (sets of vectors) and $\textrm{cov}(\mathbf A)$, $\textrm{cov}(\mathbf B)$ and $\textrm{cov}(\mathbf A - \mathbf B)$ exists, are these equations correct?

\begin{align}
\textrm{cov}(\mathbf A - \mathbf B) &= \textrm{cov}(\mathbf A)-\textrm{cov}(\mathbf B)\\
\textrm{mean}(\mathbf A - \mathbf B) &= \textrm{mean}(\mathbf A)-\textrm{mean}(\mathbf B)
\end{align}

If not, under what circumstances they are correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expected value is a linear operator, so mean($A-B$) = mean($A$) - mean($B$) for all $A$, $B$.

Covariance is not a linear operator, so cov($A-B$) = cov($A$) - cov($B$) is generally **false** except for crafted corner cases (i.e. just as $x + y = x y$ if $x,y = 0$ or $x,y = 2$ but is generally false).

Comment: Isn't it true that, in theory, if A and B are independent such that $σ(A_i, B_j) = 0$ for all rows i, j, then cov(A - B) = cov(A) - cov(B)? If so, it's not exactly a "crafted corner case" — in theory. In practice, however, it is extremely unlikely to happen with real data, so I suppose it's not that different from a "crafted corner case".

Comment: @BenHocking: I think you mean cov(A - B) = cov(A) + cov(B)

Comment: Well, it's not what I _meant_, but it's what I _should've_ meant. :)
(Well, actually, if I'd spotted my error, I wouldn't have phrased it that way at all, but merely stated that for the independent case cov(A + B) = cov(A) + cov(B) or somesuch, and so it's easy to make the mistake I made if one has exhausted one's brain cells for the day.)